# Unable to install org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.nature in Spring Tools 4 / Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, aspectj, spring-tool-suite

I just downloaded the latest Spring Tools 4 package, 4.3.2 RELEASE. My code base makes widespread use of AspectJ, and every time I try to import a project, I get a "Marketplace solutions available" dialog saying my IDE is missing natures to properly support my projects. It offers org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature as a solution, but the marketplace won't install it. When I try to access it directly through the Eclipse marketplace in my browser, I get an error dialog saying it's not compatible with this version of Eclipse. I'm using Java 11 on Linux. It's a little hard to figure out which version of Eclipse is embedded in this tool, but it appears to be Eclipse Equinox. Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: "Equinox" is just a component of Eclipse not the release version. According to the STS web site 4.3.2 is based on Eclipse 2019-06

Comment: Does _Help > Install New Software..._ and work with [`http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/48/dev/update`](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/48/dev/update) fix your issue?

Comment: Thanks, howlger. That solved it. No idea why I could not find that reference in my initial search.

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by howlger http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/48/dev/update was the missing piece of information. That solves the problem, everything builds.